# How to change the BaseURL [HOST] in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the below code and I am using [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy):

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

var baseUrl2 = "https://localhost:5002";
var app = express();

app.use('/api', proxy(baseUrl2, {
    // I want to change the baseUrl2 before making the request. 
    proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => {    
        const modifiedURL = "/someChanges"  
        return require('url').parse(modifiedURL).path;
      },
}));
app.listen(3000);
```

I am able to change the url from `https://localhost:5002` to  `https://localhost:5002/someChange`.

But I need to change it from `https://localhost:5002` to `https://localhost:5001` or `https://example.com`.

Comment: `res.redirect('https://example.com')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change the port using `proxyReqOptDecorator` option. I am changing port using `proxyReqOpts.port` but we can also change the host using `proxyReqOpts.host`

Updated Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

var baseUrl2 = "https://localhost:5002";
var app = express();

app.use('/api', proxy(baseUrl2, {
    // I want to change the baseUrl2 before making the request. 
    proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => {    
        const modifiedURL = "/someChanges"  
        return require('url').parse(modifiedURL).path;
      },

    proxyReqOptDecorator: (proxyReqOpts, srcReq) => {

        if(someCondition)
            proxyReqOpts.port = 5001;
        else
            proxyReqOpts.port = 5002;

        return proxyReqOpts;
    }
}));
app.listen(3000);
```